# Javascript pattern: ( function(){} (function(){}) )

Tags: javascript, design-patterns

I apologize in advance if this question is very simple, I'm a beginner in JavaScript.

I found a wealth of information about a [resembling pattern](http://www.adequatelygood.com/JavaScript-Module-Pattern-In-Depth.html) (module pattern) but unless I am mistaken, this is either something different or an extension. Here is a typical code excerpt from the (wonderful) [domjs project](https://github.com/medikoo/domjs) by Mariusz Nowak:

```
renameReserved = (function (rename) {
    return function (scope) {
        Object.keys(scope).forEach(rename, scope);
    };
}(function (key) {
    if (contains.call(reserved, key)) {
        this['_' + key] = this[key];
        delete this[key];
    }
}));
```

I am finding it difficult to understand exactly what's happening here, even though each part taken independently is quite simple. Detailed help would be greatly appreciated, or a link to where I could learn more about this.

Comment: Note: I am currently reading about design patterns in JavaScript (http://addyosmani.com/resources/essentialjsdesignpatterns/book/) but haven't gone through all of it yet, maybe my answer is there in which case I'm sorry.

Comment: I'm not sure what part's confusing you, so I'd suggest just sitting down and going through the evaluation of that expression step by step. If you get to a point where you don't know what happens next, then adding that to the question would clear things up.

Comment: Also without knowing what "contains" and "reserved" are, it's hard to explain why that code is written the way it is.

Comment: @Pointy Thanks a lot for your comments; what I find difficult to understand is what will happen upon a call of `renameReserved`? The variables `contains` and `reserved` come from EcmaScript5 (from a `required` instruction at the beginning of the program).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to rewrite the code in a way that won't change what happens, but may make it a little clearer:

```
function makeNameReplacer( rename ) {
    return function( scope ) {
        Object.keys(scope).forEach(rename, scope);
    }
}

function reservedWordRenamer( key ) {
    if (contains.call(reserved, key)) {
        this['_' + key] = this[key];
        delete this[key];
    }
}

renameReserved = makeNameReplacer( reservedWordRenamer );
```

So the first function is something that creates a function. The created function applies a name-substitution strategy to all the property names in a given object ("scope").

The second function is a strategy for replacing property names. Specifically, it checks to see if the property name passed in ("key") is in the set of reserved words. If it is, it replaces it with the name prefixed by an underscore, and removes the old property.

Thus the overall effect is that "renameReserved" becomes a function, one that takes an object as a parameter and which will scrub out property names that are reserved words.

You could come up with another strategy, and make another function. For example, if you wanted objects whose property names were all upper-case, you could do this:

```
function upperCaseRenamer( key ) {
  var uckey = key.toUpperCase();
  if (key !== uckey) {
      this[uckey] = this[key];
      delete this[key];
  }
}

renameLowerCase = makeNameReplacer( upperCaseRenamer );
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, this is perfectly clear; I would call this pattern a "functional" (a function of functions, which is actually exactly what it reads..). I'm really amazed by the simplicity with which such sophisticated concepts can be rendered in JavaScript! Thanks again for your explanation.

Answer (score 3):

There are two functions involved here. First one

```
function (rename) {
    return function (scope) {
        Object.keys(scope).forEach(rename, scope);
    };
}
```

And the other function object is passed as an argument to this function

```
function (key) {
    if (contains.call(reserved, key)) {
        this['_' + key] = this[key];
        delete this[key];
    }
}
```

Since we execute the first function, with an argument, (`rename` is the parameter which holds the function object passed) it returns another function which holds the function which we passed as argument because of the closure property.

Comment: So then `renameReserved` will be the function returned by the first anonymous function (of rename), in which the first parameter of `forEach` is the second anonymous function (of key)?